# Asus Vivobook Ryzen 6000 suspend problem

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, asus

When I close the lid, my laptop does not suspend at all, as if nothing happened. However, if I open the Logs app, I can find the "Lid closed" or "Lid closed".

Logs:

[image: Logs]

I have following lines in logind.conf:

```
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

Furthermore, suspend also does not work properly if I choose it in the "Power Off" menu: the screen goes black and turned off, but the laptop keeps working and will never actually turn off.

`inxi -F` output:

```
System:
  Host: martinowpc Kernel: 6.3.0-060300rc4-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME v: 44.0 Distro: Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: Vivobook_ASUSLaptop M3502RA_M3502RA
    v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: M3502RA v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: M3502RA.304 date: 12/15/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 69.6 Wh (98.4%) condition: 70.7/70.2 Wh (100.7%)
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 6800H with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP cache: L2: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1655 min/max: 1600/4784 cores: 1: 1600 2: 1600 3: 1600
    4: 1600 5: 1600 6: 1600 7: 3200 8: 1600 9: 1365 10: 1364 11: 1600 12: 1600
    13: 1600 14: 1600 15: 1358 16: 1600
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Rembrandt [Radeon 680M] driver: N/A
  Device-2: IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8 driver: X:
    loaded: vesa unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon dri: swrast gpu: N/A
    resolution: 2880x1620~91Hz
  API: OpenGL Message: Unable to show GL data. Required tool glxinfo
    missing.
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor driver: snd_pci_acp6x
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.3.0-060300rc4-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: MEDIATEK MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
    driver: mt7921e
  IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: 34:6f:24:bf:98:c5
  IF-ID-1: br-42d8c0a4c51e state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: 02:42:75:7b:31:73
  IF-ID-2: br-d0f9a736c014 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: 02:42:0d:6e:55:25
  IF-ID-3: br-ef8582f61c9e state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: 02:42:b9:a0:43:6f
  IF-ID-4: docker0 state: down mac: 02:42:d3:f8:94:97
  IF-ID-5: veth2a7fdc5 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: 4a:b3:f1:02:23:15
  IF-ID-6: veth2cc8f85 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: 2a:f2:f8:ed:fc:af
  IF-ID-7: veth5231370 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: 32:e3:0d:54:10:35
  IF-ID-8: veth65ae672 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: 6e:69:13:44:fc:7f
  IF-ID-9: veth8fddbf3 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: 92:44:71:ac:13:00
  IF-ID-10: veth90f5d63 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: a2:bf:64:f1:a0:0e
  IF-ID-11: veth945da21 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: 7e:be:e8:b1:8f:e8
  IF-ID-12: vethb52c1a1 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: 86:c7:73:ab:91:0d
  IF-ID-13: vethd615c27 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: 4a:e0:ab:dd:ee:37
  IF-ID-14: vethf1f4804 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: 06:2a:d2:e4:9d:8a
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: IMC Networks Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: 34:6F:24:BF:98:C4 bt-v: 3.0
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 92.26 GiB (9.7%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: WD PC SN735
    SDBPNHH-1T00-1002 size: 953.87 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 311.15 GiB used: 92.19 GiB (29.6%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 66.8 MiB (69.6%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 1.91 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 61.2 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 445 Uptime: 4h 22m Memory: 14.87 GiB used: 3.94 GiB (26.5%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.25
```

I have tried 6.1, 6.2 and now latest 6.3 kernels. Does anyone have any suggestions on fixing the problem?

Comment: The first thing to do is not use unsupported kernels. Such as 6.2 and 6.3 Why did you move away from the kernel the OS came with in the first place? What is the version of Ubuntu that you are using?

Comment: Closing the lid on your laptop should invoke Hibernation. You need at least as much swap as you have RAM to hibernate.

Comment: The OS comes with 6.2 - Ubuntu 23.04
Why hibernation? I could always normally suspend on lid closing on all my previous laptops.

Comment: Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community. Your question appears to relate to Ubuntu 23.04, which is an unreleased version, and therefore, not supported in this forum. For details, please review the Help Center: https://askubuntu.com/help.